# Load arbitrary JS URL into the context of current page in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome, I have the jQuerify Chrome extension that allows me to inject jQuery to the current page so that I can then play around using jQuery in the console.

I'd like to do this with other arbitrary Javascripts. Is there a way to do that natively in Chrome e.g. something like `load("http://example.com/foo.js");` in the console. Or do I need to write an extension?

Or if another popular browser can do it natively that would be good too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe they have, but it's a one-liner:

```
document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = "http://example.com/foo.js";
```

...or use a three-line version with a temp var, but that gets messier:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://example.com/foo.js";
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

This functionality isn't built into the browser. That said, jQuerify has been implemented as a Chrome extension: several actually. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/indebdooekgjhkncmgbkeopjebofdoid/ looks like a reasonable implementation. It would be fairly easy to write your own extension that injected some other library in the same manner.